# querydsl instanceof results in wrong query for hibernate Type(1)

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, querydsl

If I use Hibernate Inheritance entities I could easily always try to load only the subclass I need like this

```
SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE TYPE(p) = ?1
```

trying to achieve the same query with queryDSL:

```
QProduct.product.instanceOfAny(clazz)
```

But I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Product] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
```

query that querydsl produces is

```
SELECT count(product)
FROM Product product
WHERE product.class = ?1  // this should be TYPE(product) = ?1
```

my enitity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Product {

    ...
```

Full Stack Trace (for a similar case but different Class name):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [BasketDiscount] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$JpaPositionalParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAUtil.setConstants(JPAUtil.java:55)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:128)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.count(AbstractJPAQuery.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 94 more
```

Comment: Which Querydsl version do you use?

Comment: Could you also provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: hi @TimoWestkämper, I found your google groups' discussion on this problem, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/CoDyG0rrhTw

Comment: Could you create a ticket for it on GitHub? https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl Hibernate hasn't supported the type() syntax, that's why the .class syntax is used in Querydsl.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was discussed and solved in querydsl github repository,

and as [@Timo mentions](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1123#issuecomment-76148771) the fix will be using the version 3.6.2

> It should be available in 3.6.2

Comment: 3.6.2. is now released.